# Release apk breaking app Android Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Im getting a very strange error. I can run my application from android studio and I can load the app after runnung gradle build using the android-debug-unaligned.apk, however when i attempt to load the release.apk or the android-release-unaligned.apk, it fails on the first activity. build.gradle is below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.mysite.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local'
        credentials {
            username = 'username'
            password = 'password'
        }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.mysite', name: 'lib', version: '2.4', ext: 'aar')
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')

    def password = null
    def keystore_path = null
    def console = System.console()
    if (console != null) {
        keystore_path = console.readLine("Enter keystore path: ")
        password = console.readLine("Enter keystore password: ")
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(keystore_path)
                storePassword (password)
                keyAlias "maithuandroidkey"
                keyPassword (password)
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard true
                proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
                proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Im noticing two errors in the log cat. The first one, i think might be the error but i dont understand why it works in debug mode...

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.b.b.x cannot be cast to com.mysite.e.g
        at com.mysite.MedicApplication.u(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysite.MedicApplication.t(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysite.c.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This one pops up on the debug apk but doesnt seem to break the app.

```
E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13175)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any help on why this is happening only for release apk's would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you intending to run ProGuard? In any event, it's difficult to diagnose your stack trace given the obfuscated class names.

Comment: I have no idea why, but i removed proguard, and now it works...